# Uso del pretérito y el imperfecto: ¿por qué se dice "el viejo médico 'hubo' de hacer un viaje..."?

Tags: pretérito-imperfecto, pretérito-perfecto

> Además, como era tiempo de las lluvias y el viejo médico **hubo** de hacer al efecto de un viaje de tres kilómetros, llegó con barro hasta las rodillas y su reuma se agravó considerablemente.

Esta frase es de Josefa Martin Garcia.

¿Por qué usa el pretérito en vez del imperfecto?

Comment: Estás confundiendo conceptos. Llamas *pretérito* al pretérito perfecto simple, e *imperfecto* al pretérito imperfecto. Repasa esto en otras preguntas que has hecho, porque en algunas te hablado sobre esta cuestión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque está hablando de algo que se produjo antes de la acción principal de la frase. Es decir, el médico, en el pasado, llegó con barro hasta las rodillas, porque antes que eso el médico "hubo de hacer".

Comment: Aquí es importante el hecho de que la acción principal también se expresa en pretérito (indefinido, en este caso). Por eso este tiempo verbal se llama *pretérito anterior*: expresa algo que sucede antes de otro hecho del pasado.

Comment: @Gorpik el pretérito anterior sería «hubo hecho».  «hubo de hacer» sería intercambiable por «tuvo que hacer» o «haría/iba a hacer» (pero para la segunda opción, normalmente sería «había de hacer»)

Comment: @guifa Tienes toda la razón, leí mal la pregunta.